# Send Data from Cassandra to DataTables (NoSQL)

Tags: javascript, php, cassandra, datatables, nosql

Hey Guys I have a problem. I`m new to Cassandra and DataTables and my task is to send data from our 'Cassandra-Server' to the Table plug-in 'DataTables'.
I was looking for some examples or tutorials but I never found one for Cassandra-NoSQL.

I tried the following and this Error is always occurring:

PHP:

```
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include 'connect.php';

$statement  = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM table1");

$result     = $session->execute($statement);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var table = $('#main').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
           "url": "php/server-side.php",
            "type": "GET"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "type1" },
            { "data": "type2" },
            { "data": "type3" },
            { "data": "land" },
            {
                "data":         "id",
                "orderable":    false
            }
        ],
        "order": [[0, 'asc']]
    });
});
```

Error:

```
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 
jquery.dataTables.min.js: 39*
```

I think DataTables don't know what to do with the information (json/$data).

In this example https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html
sspclass.php is used but it is written in SQL so no use for me =(

Can somebody help me with this specific problem?